# ajax add to cart module don't update shopping cart until page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

hi I am using ajax add to cart module, after I click add to cart, pop up appear that my item has been add to cart, but my cart doesn't update until I refresh the page.

here is my cartcontroller.php code

```
class AW_Ajaxcartpro_CartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function removeAction()
{
    $response = Mage::getModel('ajaxcartpro/response');
    $id =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem($id)->save();
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_checkout')) {
        $response->setCart(Mage::helper('ajaxcartpro')->renderBigCart());
        if(AW_Ajaxcartpro_Helper_Data::RETURN_CARTBAR_ON_BIGCART)
            $response->setCartbar(Mage::helper('ajaxcartpro')->renderCart());
    } else {
        $response->setCart(Mage::helper('ajaxcartpro')->renderCart());
    }
    $response->setLinks(Mage::helper('ajaxcartpro')->renderTopCartLinkTitle());
    $_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    if($_quote && $_quote->getHasError()) $response->setError('quote error');
    $response->send();
}
}
```

where should I edit the code

Answer (score 1):

Your php code is not enough to solve the problem, this class just create a html page from your model, but for changing the shopping cart on your page without refreshing current page, you must update page elements (at least shopping cart) after receiving success response data (from ajax) with JavaScript DOM

Comment: hi did u mean I should edit my fronted/base/default/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml??

what code/javascript should be add??

Comment: for working with ajax use this link below:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

after success: you can modified your shopping cart with jquery or ajax according to your php model or just use response php page to update whole of shopping cart with ajax response

Comment: thanks a lot darkmaze I will try your method and will report later.